# Turn off built-in display ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Tags: display, 18.04

I have ubuntu 18.04 LTS installed with gnome 3.28.1. In settings I can't find a switcher which turns built-in display off. I proceeded settings->devices->displays. And there is no buttons as were on 17.10. How can I turn the display off either via bash or GUI?
[See a screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uNG36.jpg)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the *Single display* tab instead of *Join displays* tab.

Answer (score 3):

In the part where the two screens are numbered, you can adjust which one you want to be the primary display by sliding the screens over each other with your mouse cursor.

Once you choose your primary display -the one you want to use-, click on <kbd>Single Display</kbd> and by doing that, screen number one will work, whereas the second one will turn off automatically.

Comment: @Fabby, thank you for your comment, but that was not the case.. I literally described the process that I do at work with my PC: I use a Samsung screen as a second display. And I had the same problem at the beginning then I fixed it, so I described what I did.
Unfortunately, it is weekend here -the second display is at work-, or I would upload a screenshot about that.

Comment: Understood.  An edit and an upvote until the timing becomes more clear.  Removing my original comment.

Comment: Thank you.
I came here to learn more about Ubuntu and to help whenever I can, I would never steal others' answers, my purpose is not gaining reputations, it is gaining more knowledge about Ubuntu.
Another thing : I started typing my answer first (there was no answer when I started writing my answer),  but since my answer is more detailed it took more time to finish it. And when I finished, I found another answer, I thought about deleting mine since they are almost the same, but I let it because it is more detailed.
However if you or anyone else has any problem with that, I will delete it.

Comment: Keep as is because if you delete the Answer, you'll lose the reputation that now goes with the answer...